# Why doesn't jQuery UI datepicker work in jQuery dialog modal?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I want to use jQuery UI datepicker in one of my text inputs. This one is in a dialog modal.

In fact, I can call datepicker in the normal document text inputs and i got my calender normally but I can't do that in dialog modal text inputs (after clinking inside modal text input I got nothing without any JavaScript error).

**This is my code to call datepicker :**

```
$(function() {
    $("#MytextInputID").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
);
```

I tried changing css .ui-datepicker Z-index properties but I still got nothing.

Do you have tips to fix this problem ?

Regards,

---

in my_page.html i have

```
function openSaisieARModal()
        {
            window_select_CodeAgence = new showModalWindow('SaisieARModal', 500);
        }
```

And i use this script

```
var showModalWindow=function(id, width)
{
    var newId=id+'Copy';
    this.id=newId;
```

```
var previousNode=document.getElementById(newId);
if(previousNode!=null)
{
    previousNode.parentNode.removeChild(previousNode);
}

var rootNode=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
this.node=document.createElement("div");
rootNode.appendChild(this.node);
this.node.setAttribute('id', newId);
this.node.setAttribute('title', document.getElementById(id).getAttribute('title'));
this.node.innerHTML=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
if(width==null)
{
    width=400;
}
$('#'+newId).dialog({autoOpen: true, modal: true, width:width });

this.closeWindow=function()
{
    $('#'+this.id).dialog('close');
}

this.centerContent=function()
{
    this.node.style.textAlign='center';
}

this.center=function()
{
    $('#'+this.id).dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
}
```

}

and this is the modal HTML code in my_page.html

```
<div style="display:none;">
        <div id="SaisieARModal" title="DATE">
            <table class="tableFrame" cellspacing="0px" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="topLeft">

                    </td>
                    <td class="topCenter">

                    </td>
                    <td class="topRight">

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="middleLeft">

                    </td>
                    <td class="middleCenter">
                        <table>
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td>
                                    Date
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="MyTextInputID" type="text"  />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="middleRight">

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bottomLeft">

                    </td>
                    <td class="bottomCenter">

                    </td>
                    <td class="bottomRight">

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I make the assumption that you changed the value to something pretty large on the z-index (9999)?

Comment: Indeed, but also I tried 1000 -> 1003 without any change

Comment: You included the code to call the datepicker but didn't say when it's running.  I'd check 1) that it's running and 2) that it's running *after* the modal is created and #MytextInputID exists in the DOM so that datepicker can be bound.  Firebug breakpoints can help you with this.

Comment: You said clicking gave you a javascript error, can you update the question and include what that error is?

Comment: To Brian Pan 
1) Yes the code which call the datepicker run normally cause their is no problem when calling in normal text input (e.g. any text input not including in my modal)

2) of corse it's running after the modal is created cause datepicker is called when I click in the text input "MytextInputID" included in my modal (So I can't call datepicker before the modal is created)

Comment: To Nick Craver 
There is no JavaScript error. On the contrary, I said "after clinking inside modal text input I got nothing without any JavaScript error"
Thanks for all

Answer (score 19):

I mocked up a quick example that works.  You tried changing the z-index on `ui-datepicker` but after looking through the rendered code in Firebug it looks like the id you want is `ui-datepicker-div`.  I set the z-index to 9999 and it appears on top of the modal dialog.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
  $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
  });

  function openmodal() {   
      var $dialogContent = $("#event_edit_container");       

      $dialogContent.dialog({
         modal: true,
         title: "Test",
         close: function() {},
         buttons: {
          save : function() {},
          cancel : function() {}
         }
      }).show();
      $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("z-index", "9999");   
  }
</script>

<div ><a href="javascript:openmodal();">Open modal</a></div>
<div id="event_edit_container" >
    <form>
        Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: this line 
`$("#ui-datepicker-div").css("z-index", "9999");`
helped my issue. thanks .

Comment: +1 - Helped me fix my issue - keep in mind that you may need to put a slight delay via setTimeout() on that .css() if your datepicker is still not working using this fix - as mine was doing quite a bit of beforeShow: activity, and the .css() was running BEFORE the dialog was built.

Answer (score 8):

If setting

```
#ui-datepicker-div {z-index:1003;}
```

doesn't work, try

```
#ui-datepicker-div {z-index:1003 !important;}
```

Comment: Adding !important was what finally did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Initialize date picker in *open* function of your modal dialog window as below:

1. Your date picker element:

   `<input type="text" id="myDateStr"/>`
2. Call from *open* function to initialize the datepicker from dialog box:

   'open: function () {'

   ```
       $('#myDateStr').datepicker
       ({
                             dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                             changeMonth: true,
                             changeYear: true,
                           });
       }
   ```

> This worked perfectly without any tweaks.

**No need to change any existing css class or style to change the z-index.**

Answer (score 2):

In my case I Was using ZendX Jquery helper. 
I have added the following css to fix the clip style:

```
#ui-datepicker-div {z-index:9999; clip:auto}
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css (or whatever version of jquery ui you have) modify

```
.ui-datepicker
```

class from

```
{ width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; }
```

to

```
{ width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; z-index:99999; }
```

That worked for me and date picker works excellent inside modal dialog!

Answer (score 1):

In My case, the below works better

```
$(document).on("click", ".modal-body", function () {

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'

            });

});
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer more? It's not entirely clear how this addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify which 'modal dialog' you are referring to. I'm assuming its this one:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Without seeing more of your code, its difficult. It might be useful if you post the accompanying HTML.

One thing to remember however, is that the modal dialog gives you the impression that you are opening a new window, however in reality the content is in the same HTML document as the rest of your content. This can often lead to confusion when assigning element IDs, for example, some duplicates may be specified.

I'm also assuming that you've debugged/tested to the extent that you are sure your selector is working correctly, i.e. is selecting the item(s) that you intend

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`If you simplify (for a test)

```
$('#'+newId).dialog({autoOpen: true, modal: true, width:width });
```

and make it:

```
$('#SaisieARModal').dialog({autoOpen: true, modal: true, width:width });
```

does the modal show up?
Also have you tried the `bgiframe: true` option?

Not sure any of this is totally relevent, but something is putting (most likely) the date picker behind the modal stuff somewhere.

EDIT: One other thing, if you change:

```
$(function() { $("#MytextInputID").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); });
```

to

```
    $(function() { 
       $("#MytextInputID").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
       $("#MytextInputID").click(function(){alert("working");});
    });
```

does the alert show up?